# Can't see parse error

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Working on my first PHP script that interacts with SQL. I'm so close I can smell it!

I'm trying to return the MAX date in a table and received the following message where the date should be:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tslocal/themes/myname/views/reports/get_vote_date.php
>   on line 25

Line 25 is `$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);`in the script below.

Here is the script, I've stared at it till my eyes bleed but there's the uncertainty that it's "wrong" because I'm new to this:

```
<?php # script get_vote_date

// This file contains the db info
// This file establishes a mysql connection, connects to the db and then gets the most recent vote date for a particular page (incident_id).

DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'myname');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'somepass123');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'sitename');


// make the db connection
$dbc = @mysqli_connect('DB_HOST','DB_USER','DB_PASSWORD','DB_NAME')
    OR die ('Could not connect to mysql: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

// Set the encoding
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');

// set the query variable
$query = 'SELECT MAX(rating_date) 
          FROM rating
          WHERE incident_id = $incident_id;'

//connect and run the query
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

 echo $result;

?>
```

If it's of any value, here is a screen of the table I am trying to pull data from:
[image]

Comment: Missing semicolon at the end of previous line...

Comment: The line where you initialise `$query` doesn't have a semi colon at the end - there's one terminating the SQL, but you need one after the single quote, too.

Comment: Semi colon added, now "Could not connect to mysql: Unknown MySQL server host 'DB_HOST' (1)". I'm using localhost and this constant was set. I'll keep messing around

Comment: You're not passing the constants, you're passing string. Use this instead: `mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real error — missing (actually misplaced) semicolon — is in the previous statement:

```
$query = 'SELECT MAX(rating_date) 
          FROM rating
          WHERE incident_id = $incident_id;' // <-- TODO: Put the ; outside of the string literal

//connect and run the query
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

To PHP, it syntactically looks like

```
$query = "string" $result = mysqli_query(...);
```

which is of course a parse error. Note that a semicolon inside a string literal has no special meaning to PHP — it does *not* terminate the statement (though it would produce an SQL error :) ).

Unfortunately, PHP fails to see you intent on line 22 and detects the error only on line 25.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the info